# How to remove a single command from bash autocomplete

Tags: bash, autocomplete

How do I remove a single "command" from Bash's auto complete command suggestions? I'm asking about the very first argument, the command, in auto complete, not asking "[How to disable bash autocomplete for the arguments of a specific command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96534/disable-bash-autocompletion-for-a-specific-command-only)"

For example, if I have the command `ls` and the system path also finds `ls_not_the_one_I_want_ever`, and I type `ls` and then press tab, I want a way to have removed `ls_not_the_one_I_want_ever` from every being a viable option.

I think this might be related to the `compgen -c` list, as this seems to be the list of commands available.

---

Background: WSL on Windows is putting all the `.dll` files on my path, in addition to the `.exe` files that should be there, and so I have many dlls I would like to remove in my bash environment, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash 5.0's `complete` command added a new `-I` option for this.

According to `man bash` —

> - complete -pr [-DEI] [*name* ...]
>
>   [...] The `-I` option indicates  that other  supplied  options  and actions should apply to completion on the **initial non-assignment word** on the line, or after a command delimiter such as `;` or `|`, which is usually  **command  name completion**. [...]

---

##### Example:

```sh
function _comp_commands()
{
    local cur=$2

    if [[ $cur == ls* ]]; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -c "$cur" | grep -v ls_not_wanted) )
    fi
}

complete -o bashdefault -I -F _comp_commands
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @pynexj's answer, I came up with the following example that seems to work well enough:

```sh
if [ "${BASH_VERSINFO[0]}" -ge "5" ]; then
  function _custom_initial_word_complete()
  {
    if [ "${2-}" != "" ]; then
      if [ "${2::2}" == "ls" ]; then
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -c "${2}" | \grep -v ls_not_the_one_I_want_ever))
      else
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -c "${2}"))
      fi
    fi
  }

  complete -I -F _custom_initial_word_complete
fi
```

Comment: updated my answer by giving a simple example. just to show how your script can be simplified a bit. :)